# New to coding - Trying to access a certain element from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# the website being accessed
my_url = 'https://www.theglobeandmail.com/world/article-us-election-results-map-watch-donald-trump-and-joe-bidens/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
page = requests.get(my_url)
page_soup = soup(page.content, "html.parser")

print(page_soup.prettify())

# grabs the number of votes for democrats
democrats = page_soup.find('div', {'class':"count dem"})

print(democrats)
```

this is the html for the element I am trying to access: div class="count dem">264</div

I am trying to make my own poll tracker to practice webscraping - this is my first time webscraping

Comment: Not clear what issues you're having, but that AP News widget is definitely loaded by Javascript. Beautifulsoup cannot load Javascript - Use selenium instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page contents are loaded dynamically, so you have to use `selenium`. Plus, the needed part (the dem count) is present within an `iframe`, which is present under another `iframe`. So you have to switch focus to the needed `iframe` in order to grab the count. All this can be done just with `selenium` without using `BeautifulSoup`. Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# the website being accessed
my_url = 'https://www.theglobeandmail.com/world/article-us-election-results-map-watch-donald-trump-and-joe-bidens/'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(my_url)
time.sleep(5)

iframe1 = driver.find_element_by_id('iframe_7926bd7885766f673401d33df30e0cdc')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe1)
iframe2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ap-embed')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2)

democrats = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.count.dem')
print(democrats.text)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
264
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  How would I turn the output from a web element into an int?

Comment: The output, which is `264`, is a `str`. In order to turn it into an `int`, just typecast it into an `int`, like this: `print(int(democrats.text))`

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the `BackEnd` directly via the `API`

```
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    goal = r['results']['US'][0]['summary']['results'][0]['electWon']
    print(goal)


main("https://interactives.ap.org/elections/live-data/production/2020-11-03/president/summary.json")
```

Output:

```
264
```